# How to get the quote address object when user logged in?

Tags: get, magento-1.7, quote

One particular user logged in to his account from frontend and add some items to the shopping cart. And then he logged out. And again when he logged in I want to get his quote address object.

How to achieve this? Is there any event which fires and I can get the quote address object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$quote= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();//this will try to load the quote by current logged in customer if customer previously left any
$quote->getBillingAddress();//should return billng address object, if current quote has any billling address set
$quote->getShippingAddress();//should return shipping address object, if current quote has any shipping address set
```

Hope this help !